# What do the +x, +y values represent on weapons?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

My guess is...

x = accuracy
y = damage

...but I figured I'd ask just to be sure.

I checked the wiki pretty thoroughly but couldn't find any info on these two values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You guessed right.

The first + is a bonus to your accuracy, meaning the chance that your attack connect with the enemy.

The second is a damage bonus, which is, of course, only applied if your attack actually hit the enemy.

Note that missiles can only have an accuracy bonus, not damage.

Source: [Scroll of enchant weapon](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/index.php?title=Scrolls_of_enchant_weapon)